# How is Java Applet implemented in the web browsers?

Tags: java, applet, browser

I am interested in the implementations/internals of Java Applet, but didn't find any resources on line.

Specifically, I am interested in how the classes are downloaded (when and which classes), are they downloaded on demand?

If you know any resources discussing about this, could you refer it to me? Or if you are expert in that, could you explain it here?

Comment: not a expert , but AFAIK , first when you call an applet from a browser , it downloads the applet class file on the client system  and till the class file is available on the client system , you can use the applet , the applet class will not be downloaded for all request but first

Comment: Applets aren't implemented in the browser itself. The Java installation has a plugin that basically gets handed a window to draw in by the browser, and everything else is in the JRE. For the applet classloading process, [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/misc/classloader.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [class loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) loads the bytes of the classes into the JVM. In case of the applets the class loader is a subclass of [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). A different classloader object is used for each web site. Also see this: [Java™ Plug-in and Applet Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html)